# Can not get a value from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I want to get the value of column 'no' from the database and after that i want to mail this value to the user, but i got some error..

Here is the query which i have written for getting the value in the model and the function sendmail() which i have written to send the mail to the user in the controller..

**Model: User_model**

```
public function get_client_id()
{   

    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT no FROM users WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $value = mysql_fetch_object($result);
    $_SESSION['myid'] = $value->no;
}
```

**Controller: Users.php**

```
public function sendmail()
    {
        $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'something@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '******',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );

        $data = $this->user_model->get_client_id();

        $message = print($_SESSION['myid']);


        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->from('dharavihol119@gmail.com', 'Dhara Vihol');
        $this->email->to($_SESSION["email"]);

        $this->email->subject('You have successfully signed up');
        $this->email->message($message);


        if ( ! $this->email->send())
        {
            echo "There is some error!";
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Mail is sent successfully";
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }


    }
```

And these errors are being shown...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqAyR.png

But the mail is sent to the user and it always prints the 1 into the mail.

Please help me.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Codeigniter then why are you using `mysql_fetch_object` ??

Please change your code as below :

In your model

```
public function get_client_id()
{   

    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT no FROM users WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1");
$query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->row();
   return $result->no;
}
```

In your controller, Instead of

```
 $data = $this->user_model->get_client_id();

    $message = print($_SESSION['myid']);
```

use this

```
 $message = $this->user_model->get_client_id();
```

Comment: Thank you Drudge. It works!!

Comment: @DharaVihol If it is usefull to you then  please accept the answer so that it can be useful to others as well  .

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter you don't need to call `mysql_fetch_object()` as CodeIgniter has all the database layer written for you, the call you made just before will return an array with the results in it already (`$result = $query->result_array();`).

To properly use CodeIgniter's database layer, take the following for example:

```
public function get_client_id()
{   
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT no FROM users WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1");
    $result = $query->row(); 
    return $result->no;
}
```

This will get the first row of your query response and return just the value `no` from the result.

Then in your `sendmail()` function you can change:

```
$data = $this->user_model->get_client_id();

$message = print($_SESSION['myid']);
```

to simply

```
$message = $this->user_model->get_client_id();
```

There is no need to pass the id in the `SESSION` array, unless you're storing it there for later use (in which case go right ahead! Just add that code back to my example code)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I must say your answer explained more..Thank you..